# Bar / Line Chart % Based on Slicer

Tags: powerbi

Having trouble to set a title on this so feel free to edit.

I have data structured roughly like this:

| Project | Resource | Department | Hours |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Dwight | Sales | 2 |
| 2 | Jim | Sales | 4 |
| 3 | Creed | Quality | 1 |
| 4 | Jim | Sales | 3 |
| 5 | Creed | Quality | 2 |
| 6 | Michael | Corporate | 8 |

My intent is to show the trend of department hours per project over time.

I can make an easy bar / line chart for this - the issue is I need this to be a % vs just SUM of hours.  I have a slicer to pick a department which works but again just adjusts the SUM.

All projects vary in total hours - need to see which departments are trending up / down.  I am pretty sure I could make a standalone visual for departments based on custom measures with filters etc.  Looking to make this 100% dynamic.